# Angular directive to fetch resources to fill a table

Tags: javascript, json, angular.js, ajax

I created a directive that solves my immediate problem, but I'm trying to find ways to make it more reusable.

My immediate problem was, I have a table and needed to fill in one of the columns with data from an http request. I passed an object (dir.provider.resource) and a string (attr) into the directive, made a GET request with its href, and then displayed the value gotten from resource[attr].

HTML:

```
<td class="col-status" ng-if="resource">
  <get-resource-property passedResource="dir.provider.resource" attr="status"></get-resource-property>
</td>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('getResourceProperty', function ($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        passedResource: '=',
        attr: '='
      },
      template: '<td>{{result}}</td>',
      link: function postLink(scope, element) {
        var resource = scope.passedResource;
        var attr = scope.attr;

        if (resource) {
          http.get(resource.href)
           .then(function (resource) {
              setScope(resource);
          });
        }

        function setScope(resource) {
          scope.result = resource[attr];
          if (attr === 'status') {
             //do specific stuff with the status here
             var color = resource[attr] === 'ON' : 'green' ? 'red';
             element.css("color", color);
          }
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

It would be really useful to make this more reusable, as I have to work with a lot of nested resources in my project. Take the example below:

```
{ 
  href: "httsp://site.com/resource/12345",
  otherResource: {
     href: "https://site.com/other-resource/678910"
  },
  relatedResource: {
     href: "https://site.com/resource/12345/related-resource/"
  },
  ...
}
```

If I want to access a property in relatedResource, I have to make a GET request before I can do so. Sometimes I just need to get one value (like in the above example, I just need to get a nested resource's status), so I can see this being useful in these types of cases..

Am I thinking about this right, or am I missing something obvious? Does anything stand out from the code that looks off? (I am new to angular, so any tips would be great!)

Comment: how do you pass the nested resource? In other words, how do you know when to call a nested resource and when not to?

Answer (score 1):

## Promise Simplification

> ```
> http.get(resource.href)
>     .then(function (resource) {
>         setScope(resource);
>     });
> ```

could be simplified to:

```
http.get(resource.href)
    .then(setScope);
```

Beware of the scenario where the `.then` callback passes more arguments than the callback function is ready to handle.

## Single-use variables

There is little use in assigning a variable that is only used once after it is declared. For example:

> ```
> var color = resource[attr] === 'ON' : 'green' ? 'red';
> element.css("color", color);
> ```

could be simplified to:

```
element.css("color", resource[attr] === 'ON' : 'green' ? 'red');
```

Comment: There's often value in assigning a use-once variable - to give it a useful name - but that clearly isn't the case here.